# Mysql JSON type have messy code using spring data jpa

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have set MySQL's character set to utf8mb4, and it works fine for varchar type, saving and reading Chinese character works fine.

But when it comes to JSON type, saving works fine, while reading JSON as string using spring-data-jpa, it get messy code.

I have tried the below settings, it doesn't work.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TAIMIROBOT?&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.init-sql="SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;"
```

Comment: check for any sort of conversion that is happening when reading the file.

Comment: May you please show the sample output of JSON that you read.

Comment: { "items":[{"itemName":"纱布","needed":4,"added":0}]}，this is what I am trying to read. But in the actual output, "纱布" has become “çº±å¸”.

Comment: Seems a known issue for mysql: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed.  [bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80631](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80631)

> ResultSet.getString() sometimes returned garbled data for columns of the
>   JSON data type. This was because JSON data was binary encoded by MySQL using
>   the utf8mb4 character set, but decoded by Connector/J using the ISO-8859-1
>   character set.
>
> The fix has been included in Connector/J 6.0.5. The entry for the 5.1.40
>   changelog has been included into the 6.0.5 changelog.

If you have the same problem, just update your connector version in your maven pom file to 6.0.5 (if you are using maven).